# Board game fun for 3 year old AND parent

Tags: recommendations

I like playing board game with my 3 year old son. But it can be boring sometimes for me. Is there a game that is designed to be playable by a 3 year old, but also interesting for the adults playing it? Maybe different rules for the players?

Comment: See this period as an investment. Yes those kid games can be boring, but they make the kid interested in games and in a few years you will have a willing game player in the house.

Comment: I definitely agree with that, and happily do it. I thought if there's a way to make it better for me, it'd be great though.